# How to hide a field based on a specific condition?

Tags: entities, nodes

I have a website for ads, which are either of those:

- Regular ads.
- VIP ads.

The Regular ads have an additional field "`field_adding_make_vip`". If the user decides to change a Regular ad to a VIP ad, the user will use the description from that field and send a SMS to a specific number and that ad will become automatically a VIP ad.

The filter in Views to show the VIP content is a additional field "`field_vip_date`" that uses a date filter. That mechanism is created with a custom PHP file.

So only left to do is: when the Regular ad becomes a VIP ad, the field "`field_adding_make_vip`" will be automatically hidden and the VIP ad will have additional field "`field_adding_vip_image`" that will show a VIP image, so every user will know that the selected ad is a VIP ad.

How can I hide that field and show the VIP image when the ad becomes a VIP ad?

The Regular ad and VIP ad are the same content type (adding). I'm using the field "`field_vip_date`" as a filter in views by date. Let's say when the date field of a specific node is set to 25 October, that node will be displayed in a VIP block position in the website until 25 of October and the next day it will be automatically removed from that position. That's for a block view position.

In every page node the field "`field_adding_make_vip`" has a description with the node id how to send the SMS, to be used to make it a VIP ad. The whole idea is when the user sends an SMS with the number ID, the field "`field_adding_make_vip`" will disappear, because the regular node has become a VIP ad and that node will have an additional field "`field_adding_vip_image`" that will display an image with a text "VIP".

Somehow the field "`field_vip_date`" (which is a date field) will have to control the field "`field_adding_make_vip`". For an example if "`node/120`" has "`field_vip_date`" set to 25 October, the field "`field_adding_make_vip`" will be hidden until 26 October and the field "`field_adding_vip_image`" will be displayed until 26 October.

**Note**: I've tried the code from @harshal, but it has errors. The name of my custom module is "`custom_alter`" and here's the full code:

```
<?php
function custom_alter_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

 $node = node_load($nid);
 $date = date('d/m/Y');
 $todaysdate = strtotime($date);
 $field_date_vip = $node->field_date_vip['und'][0]['value'];
 $date = date('d/m/y',  $field_date_vip);
 $expirydate = strtotime($date);



If ( $todaysdate <  $expirydate )) {
  //Hide the field adding_make_vip using css
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'custom') . '/css/hide_field_adding_make_vip.css');
             }
else {
// hide field adding_make_vip using css
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'custom') . '/css/hide_field_adding_vip_image.css');

}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you need. But if I'm correct and you just need to show / hide specific fields in a node based on some other field in that node the hook_field_access should help you.

```
 /**
 * Implements hook_field_access().
 */
function YOUR_MODULE_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
  global $user;
  switch ($field['field_name']) {
    case 'field_adding_make_vip':
      if ($node['isVIP'][value]) {  //Is the node VIP?
        return false;  //Show the field_adding_make_vip
      }
      else {
        return true; //Hide the field_adding_make_vip
      }
      break;
  }
    case 'field_adding_vip_image':
      if ($node['isVIP'][value]) {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
      break;

}
```

Comment: @Petroll Thank you for your answer. I'll post more details in the main thread.

Comment: Please check my updated thread, 'cos I cannot find a way to open a chat with you.

Answer (score 1):

> Somehow the field "field_vip_date" which is a date field will have to
>   control the field "field_adding_make_vip". For an example if
>   "node/120" has "field_vip_date" set to 25 October, the field
>   "field_adding_make_vip" will be hidden until 26 October and the field
>   "field_adding_vip_image" will be displayed until 26 October.
>   **For the part to disppear the vip image fields after expiry the code is as follows : This is just for a single node.**

```
function module_name_form_alter($form,&$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form_id == 'adding_node_form') {
       $nid = $form['nid'] ;
       $node = $node_load($nid);
$form['#submit'][] = 'adding_node_form_after_submit';
    //insert the code here

    }
}


function adding_node_form_after_submit ($form, &$form_state) {
$field_vip_date = $form['field_vip_date']['und'][0]['date'];
$expiry_date = strtotime($form['field_vip_date']['und'][0]['date']);
$date = date('d/m/Y');
$current_date = strtotime($date);
if ($current_date > $expiry_date) {
drupal_add_js( drupal_get_path('module', 'your_module_name') . '/' . custom.js);
}
}
```

Now add a js file in your custom module folder. 
In your custom.js the code goes as follows:

```
(function ($) {

  Drupal.behaviors.exampleModule = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
   // add your code here
$('.field-name-field-adding-vip-image').hide();
      });
    }
  };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I cannot understand where to put this code.

Comment: u should use it inside hook_form_alter()

Comment: I've edited my first post. Please check it.

Comment: check for the form_id and set the condition as given above in edited answer

Comment: can you send me your email, so I can send you the link of the website, because I think that we are going in a wrong direction. I didn't find a way to chat with you here.